# Mouse cursor change on mouseover, for specific classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, cursor

I got this mouseover effect that you can see on [this](https://codepen.io/dominotrix/pen/rNZqeRz?editors=0010) CodePen.

The cursor is always red, but I want it to change into a bigger (scaled) white cursor when it hovers one of the items.

`<div class="custom-cursor"></div>` (this is the cursor `div`, it's always red and via JS I make this `div` follow my cursor around).

And then we have our elements:

```
<div class="row-02-rig-sin black-cursor">
...
</div>
```

This above is the `<div>` where I want the cursor to change shape and color. To do that, I made an `eventListener` so that I can track when the mouse goes over the class name of `.black-cursor`. Here is the JS code for that:

```
document.addEventListener("mouseover", function (e) {
  if (e.target.matches(".black-cursor")) {
    customCursor.classList.add("is-hovering");
  }
});
```

The code above "should" work (and it does partially) when you hover over the `div`, but the problem is that the `e.target.matches()` is not triggering when the cursor is hovering on an element that is **inside** the `.black-cursor`.

With simple CSS I change the cursor when it is hovering over `.black-cursor` since there is `customCursor.classList.add("is-hovering");` when it returns true.

`.custom-cursor.is-hovering {background-color:#fff;width:70px;height:70px;}`

Try to play around in the CodePen, with the cursor place exactly ontop of the black horizontal bar. This is the only place that the `e.target` is equal to the correct element, so it triggers there, but nowhere else.

An easy fix would be to track if the `e.target` is a children of a `.black-cursor` parent. Or also, I could add the class name `.black-cursor` on each element so that I can ensure the cursor works. But I don't like both of these solutions. The 1st one is time consuming for the end-user due to the calculations while `mousemove` and the 2nd solution is time consuming for the developer to add the same class name to all the elements.

Is there some other solution with priority on the performance? So no lags, no fps drops would appear. I've heard of a `requestAnimationFrame` here and there but I haven't tried that yet since I dont know if it would help me.

Comment: why do you not just use CSS? `.black-cursor:hover { .... }`

Comment: But the cursor changes with CSS already. There is a `div` that is the actual cursor in red color. This `div` is following the cursor around all the time with JS, but the styling is with CSS. And then if the cursor is mouseover-ing on a `div` with `black-cursor` class, then the cursor `div` is getting a new class name called `is-hovering`, where with CSS again I change its style to scaled and white.

Comment: You really should put the code in the question and not a 3rd party site. You can make it runnable here with a snipplet. Your mouseout code is wrong, it is always removing your class.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your mouseout code smarter so it is not removing the class every time it is called.

This solution is still not perfect, but should give you a starting point.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    var customCursor = document.querySelector(".custom-cursor");
    document.addEventListener("mousemove", moveCursor);
    document.addEventListener("scroll", moveCursor);
    document.addEventListener("mouseover", function (e) {
        if (e.target.matches && e.target.matches(".black-cursor")) {
            customCursor.classList.add("is-hovering");
        }
    });
    document.addEventListener("mouseout", function (e) {
    if (e.target.closest(".black-cursor")) return;
        customCursor.classList.remove("is-hovering");
    });
    function moveCursor(e) {
        customCursor.style.top = e.clientY + "px";
        customCursor.style.left = e.clientX + "px";
    }
});
```

```css
body{
    background-color:beige;
}


.custom-cursor {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: red;
    border-radius: 100%;
    pointer-events: none;
    z-index: 9999;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
    transition: transform 0.3s ease;
  }
  .custom-cursor.is-hovering {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(4);
        background-color:white;
  }




.row-02 {
    width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    padding: 120px 0;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.row-02-rig {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 60px;
}
.row-02-rig-sin {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    position: relative;
}
.row-02-rig-sin::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: -20px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: #000;
}
.row-02-rig-sin-lef {
    background-color:aqua;
    width:100px;
    display: flex;
}
.row-02-rig-sin-rig {
    width:500px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 20px;
}
.row-02-rig-sin-rig-top {
    width:500px;
    background-color:navy;
}
.row-02-rig-sin-rig-top a {
    color: #fff;
}
.row-02-rig-sin-rig-bot {
    width:500px;
    display: flex;
    background-color:blue;
}
.row-02-rig-sin-rig-bot-lef {
    width:100px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color:pink;
    gap: 8px;
}
.row-02-rig-sin-rig-bot-rig {
    width:400px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color:blueviolet;
    gap: 8px;
}
.row-02-rig-sin-rig-bot-rig-sin {
    font-weight: bold;
}
.row-02-rig-sin-rig-bot-rig-sin br {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="custom-cursor"></div>

<div class="row-02">
    <div class="row-02-rig">

        <div class="row-02-rig-sin black-cursor">
            <div class="row-02-rig-sin-lef">.2018</div>
            <div class="row-02-rig-sin-rig">
                <div class="row-02-rig-sin-rig-top"><a href="#">PROJECT TITLE HERE</a></div>
                <div class="row-02-rig-sin-rig-bot">
                    <div class="row-02-rig-sin-rig-bot-lef">
                        <div class="row-02-rig-sin-rig-bot-lef-sin">Τοποθεσία</div>
                        <div class="row-02-rig-sin-rig-bot-lef-sin">Τομέας</div>
                        <div class="row-02-rig-sin-rig-bot-lef-sin">Προϊόντα</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row-02-rig-sin-rig-bot-rig">
                        <div class="row-02-rig-sin-rig-bot-rig-sin">ΒΙ.ΠΕ. Κιλκίς</div>
                        <div class="row-02-rig-sin-rig-bot-rig-sin">Έργα Υποδομής</div>
                        <div class="row-02-rig-sin-rig-bot-rig-sin">Τσιμεντόστυλοι</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="row-02-rig-sin black-cursor">
            <div class="row-02-rig-sin-lef">.2018</div>
            <div class="row-02-rig-sin-rig">
                <div class="row-02-rig-sin-rig-top"><a href="#">PROJECT TITLE HERE</a></div>
                <div class="row-02-rig-sin-rig-bot">
                    <div class="row-02-rig-sin-rig-bot-lef">
                        <div class="row-02-rig-sin-rig-bot-lef-sin">Τοποθεσία</div>
                        <div class="row-02-rig-sin-rig-bot-lef-sin">Τομέας</div>
                        <div class="row-02-rig-sin-rig-bot-lef-sin">Προϊόντα</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row-02-rig-sin-rig-bot-rig">
                        <div class="row-02-rig-sin-rig-bot-rig-sin">ΒΙ.ΠΕ. Κιλκίς</div>
                        <div class="row-02-rig-sin-rig-bot-rig-sin">Έργα Υποδομής</div>
                        <div class="row-02-rig-sin-rig-bot-rig-sin">Τσιμεντόστυλοι</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="row-02-rig-sin black-cursor">
            <div class="row-02-rig-sin-lef">.2018</div>
            <div class="row-02-rig-sin-rig">
                <div class="row-02-rig-sin-rig-top"><a href="#">PROJECT TITLE HERE</a></div>
                <div class="row-02-rig-sin-rig-bot">
                    <div class="row-02-rig-sin-rig-bot-lef">
                        <div class="row-02-rig-sin-rig-bot-lef-sin">Τοποθεσία</div>
                        <div class="row-02-rig-sin-rig-bot-lef-sin">Τομέας</div>
                        <div class="row-02-rig-sin-rig-bot-lef-sin">Προϊόντα</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row-02-rig-sin-rig-bot-rig">
                        <div class="row-02-rig-sin-rig-bot-rig-sin">ΒΙ.ΠΕ. Κιλκίς</div>
                        <div class="row-02-rig-sin-rig-bot-rig-sin">Έργα Υποδομής</div>
                        <div class="row-02-rig-sin-rig-bot-rig-sin">Τσιμεντόστυλοι</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/dominotrix/pen/rNZqeRz?editors=0100) is update with the correct code:

This was replaced...

```
  document.addEventListener( 'mouseover', function( e ) {
    if ( e.target.matches('.black-cursor') ) {
      customCursor.classList.add( 'is-hovering' );
    }
  });

  document.addEventListener( 'mouseout', function( e ) {
    customCursor.classList.remove( 'is-hovering' );
  });
```

...with this:

```
  jQuery('.black-cursor').mouseover(function(){
    jQuery('.custom-cursor').addClass('is-hovering');
    return false;
  }).mouseout(function(){
    jQuery('.custom-cursor').removeClass('is-hovering');
  });
```